# Show this expression transform like a covariant tensor

Tags: metric-tensor

Show that $g_{\mu v} V^{v}$ transform like a covariant vector.

$$g_{\mu' v'} V^{v'} = g_{\mu v} V^{v} \Lambda_{\mu'}^{\;\; \mu} \Lambda_{\;\; v'}^{v} \Lambda_{\;\; v}^{v'} = g_{\mu v} V^{v} \Lambda_{\mu'}^{\;\; \mu} \times(\Lambda \Lambda)^{v}_{\;v}$$

Now, the problem is this last term. Tecnically it should be the identity, but i am almost sure this is not the case, so i think i have committed an error, but where?

Comment: You've mishandled the contraction. Now you have too many copies of $\nu$.

Comment: @J.G. So maybe $$g_{\mu' v'} V^{v'} = g_{\mu v} V^{x} \Lambda_{\mu'}^{\;\; \mu} \Lambda_{\;\; v'}^{v} \Lambda_{\;\; x}^{v'} = g_{\mu v} V^{v} \Lambda_{\mu'}^{\;\; \mu} \times(\Lambda \Lambda)^{v}_{\;x}$$ ?

Comment: That's better, but when you write something like $(\Lambda\Lambda)^\nu{}_x$ it's hard to tell the tensor whose entries you're taking is (if you'll give the kind of matrix notation that works for both indices downstairs) $\Lambda^Tg\Lambda=g$, i.e. the "matrix element" in question is $g^\nu{}_x=\delta^\nu{}_x$. It's easier if you transform one factor at a time, as in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that$$g_{\mu^\prime\nu^\prime}V^{\nu^\prime}=\frac{\partial x^\mu}{\partial x^{\mu^\prime}}\frac{\partial x^\nu}{\partial x^{\nu^\prime}}g_{\mu\nu}V^{\nu^\prime}=\frac{\partial x^\mu}{\partial x^{\mu^\prime}}g_{\mu\nu}V^{\nu}.$$Feel free to rewrite the partial derivatives as $\Lambda$ entries.

Comment: Oh, i forgot this point. So we components of the lorentz transformation can always be written as partial derivative like that? I thought that were only for the metric

Comment: @LSS Well, a coefficient is a coefficient. If a $\Lambda$ entry comes up in any context, its value is always the same. As I say, you're welcome to make this look more $\Lambda$y. But working with explicit derivatives has the advantage you can easily use the chain rule, which often come up. For example, here's the entire proof the partial derivative of a scalar is a vector:$$\partial_{\mu^\prime}\phi=\frac{\partial x^\mu}{\partial x^{\mu^\prime}}\partial_\mu\phi.$$

Comment: (Besides, you won't want to think about $\Lambda$ when you reach general relativity, because you often neither know nor care how $\Lambda$ looks in your coordinate system.)